# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory when run "php artisan serve"

Tags: php, laravel, runtimeexception, temporary-files, nosuchfileexception

I uploaded a **Laravel/vue3** project to a host. Then I run **npm run build**, then **php artisan serve**. *Every thing was ok*. The projects ran successfully. After a while, when I made some changes to the project, then stopped server, then run **php artisan serve** again. **I got the following errors:

```
  Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException 
A temporary file could not be opened to write the process output: 
     fopen(/tmp\sf_proc_00.out.lock): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

 at vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPipes.php:63
     59▕                         if (file_exists($file.'.lock')) {
     60▕                             continue 2;
     61▕                         }
     62▕                         restore_error_handler();
     ➜      63▕                         throw new RuntimeException('A temporary file could 
     not be 
    opened to write the process output: '.$lastError);
```

What is the problem? I uploaded another project, and then get the same error message.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Are you seriously trying to run a LIVE site using the builtin PHP server? If you bought a hosting package, surely you bought access to a Proper Web Server like Apache

Comment: _After a while, when I made some changes to the project,_ Then look at the changes you made to the project. Thats likely where the issue started

Comment: Did you actually mean to try and access the `/tmp` directory? The leading `/` means go to the root directory and find the `tmp` directory there. I would not expect that you would be allowed access to that on a hosting package.